# Cloud Storage upload through Cloud Functions giving Error: Not Found

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

React CKEditor 5 on the front end. Trying to upload an image to Cloud Storage bucket when the user adds an image to the content of the editor. Uploading to Cloud Storage from a Cloud Function, however I'm getting `Error: Not Found` which I'm not really sure what to do with.

Here's my code:

```
module.exports = async (req) => {
    const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'tmpImage.png')
    
    fs.writeFile(tmpFilePath, req.body, (err) => {
        if(err) throw err
        fs.readFile(tmpFilePath, (err, data) => {
            console.log('Error: ', err)
            console.log('Data: ', data)
        })
    })
    
    try {
        await storage.bucket('bucketUrl').upload(tmpFilePath, {
            gzip: true,
            metadata: {
              cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
            }
          })
        return 'Something'
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('----- ERROR START -----')
        console.log(err)
        console.log('----- ERROR END -----')
        return { error: err }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Not Found
>      at new ApiError (/Users/garrettlove/development/devgrub/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:59:15)
>      at Util.parseHttpRespMessage (/Users/garrettlove/development/devgrub/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:161:41)
>      at Util.handleResp (/Users/garrettlove/development/devgrub/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:135:76)
>      at retryRequest (/Users/garrettlove/development/devgrub/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:434:22)
>      at onResponse (/Users/garrettlove/development/devgrub/functions/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:206:7)
>      at res.text.then.text (/Users/garrettlove/development/devgrub/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:150:17)
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

If you want to see the rest of the error let me know, it's a little much to post.

Answer (score 0):

The code is attempting to upload the file before it's been written to disk.  [fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) is asynchronous and returns immediately, before the write is complete.  According to the linked API documentation:

> When file is a filename, *asynchronously* writes data to the file, replacing the file if it already exists. data can be a string or a buffer.

If you want to wait until the file is fully written, consider either:

- Uploading the file only after the write is complete by using the callback function that you pass to it. The upload code should be within that callback.
- Using the version of [writeFile that deals with promises](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options) instead of callbacks, and chain the promises.
- Using [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) to write synchronously.

Comment: Cloud Functions says it works, but the react app says it can't be uploaded... I do see a file in Cloud Storage but it doesn't load when I try to view it